# XFWM set chrome app launcher placement?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, chrome

I'm running XFCE4 in arch linux and using google-chrome-stable. I added the Chrome app launcher (`google-chrome-stable --show-app-list`) to the panel, but when I click on it, it places the launcher window in the top left corner of my screen (which is inconvenient because it overlaps my launcher).

I am also using docky (bottom center), and when I place the launcher there, the same window placement behavior is used (no where near where I clicked). I can use alt-click to move the launcher window to a more desirable location, but the Chrome Launcher forgets the next time I click on it.

Running `google-chrome-stable --show-app-list` from a terminal has the same effect. Moving the panel around also does nothing.

I tried using XFCE's window manager tweaks, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there a way to set default placement?

(This is my first question on any Stack Exchange, any tips on asking better questions is appreciated!)

[image: Clicked the docky icon]

Comment: I ended up expanding the panel and disabling window overlap. However, it would be nice if I could place the launcher window right above to the dock.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my earlier comment. Enable centered app list places the launcher in the center of the screen. What I meant was right above the docky launcher/cursor. That said, the having the launcher in the center isn't a bad idea... @MartínCanaval